# How to store session data between users? Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating an e-commerce webapp in django. I'm on the part of implementing the cart. I'm using session to store the items in the cart. However, when I switch between AnoymousUser and an authenticated User, I lose the items that were in the cart. How to store this data between users?
Bellow is my cart view. carrinho = cart. produto = product

```
class ProdutosDetail(DetailView):
model = Produto
template_name = 'produto/produto_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'produto'


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    produto = request.POST.get('produto')
    carrinho = request.session.get('carrinho')
    #print(carrinho)
    if carrinho:
        quantidade = carrinho.get(produto)
        if quantidade:
            carrinho[produto] = quantidade + 1
        else:
            carrinho[produto] = 1
    else:
        carrinho = {}
        carrinho[produto] = 1
    
    request.session['carrinho'] = carrinho

    return redirect('produtos:ordemview')
```

Comment: you may have to use the database-baked sessions to store the data. see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions

Comment: better you maintain a table for cart

Comment: I was developing like this, but I realized that just by adding products to the cart, you write to the database. On a high volume of users, couldn't this overload my DB or even lead to inconsistent data?